# Downloading S3 image from browser working on one machine and giving CORS error on another machine

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-s3, cors

I have an Angular2 app and I am trying to download a set of images from S3 and put them in a zip file.  I am using the following code which I got from https://gist.github.com/noelvo/4502eea719f83270c8e9

```
dlImages(urlList, jobName) {

    var zip = new JSZip();
    var count = 0;
    var zipFilename = jobName.split(" ").join("_") + ".zip";
    var img = zip.folder("images");

    console.log(zipFilename);

    urlList.forEach(function (url, idx) {
        //filename and file type should be the same it is in s3
        var fileExtension = url.split('.').pop(-1);
        var realIdx = idx + 1;
        var filename = realIdx.toString().concat(".").concat(fileExtension);
        console.log(url);
        console.log(filename);

        JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                throw err; // or handle the error
            }
            img.file(filename, data, {binary: true});
            count++;

            if (count == urlList.length) {
                zip.generateAsync({type: 'blob'}).then(function (content) {
                    FileSaver.saveAs(content, zipFilename);
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The code is running on a Heroku app and the strange thing is that it works as intended on my development machine (chrome Version 68.0.3440.106) however it gives a CORS error on another machine (chrome Version 69.0.3497.100).  The specific CORS error is

```
Failed to load url.for.image.in.s3.jpg: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.  Origin 'https://myherokuapp.herokuapp.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The above error is thrown for every image url in the set.
 And my CORS policy for the bucket is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Also, in my app.js file I have

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    next();
});
```

Does anyone know why this CORS error is happening for this CORS policy? A follow-up question is why would this work on one machine but not the other?

EDIT:

Below are screenshots of the response headers for each of the machines when an image is attempted to be downloaded.

This is the response header for the machine that DOES work
[image]

And here is the response header for the machine that DOES NOT work

[image]

So clearly the difference is that the response header for the machine that doesn't work does not have the ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW fields, but I don't know why that is happening.  I'll do some research but if anyone knows that would be very helpful.

SECOND EDIT:

Also here is the request header for the machine that does not work

```
Origin: https://xxxxx.herokuapp.com

Referer: https://xxxxx.herokuapp.com/yyyyyyyy/5ac2635557c3f70014529d4d

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
```

The request header for the machine that does work is the same except for the user-agent.

Comment: Browser caching? Maybe try clearing your browser cache / force-reloading

Comment: Can you provide request/response headers from browser console on both machines, please?

Comment: @hd.deman Thank you for the suggestion it looks like the response headers are indeed different but I'm not sure why.  I will add the screenshots to my question

Comment: Hey could you add the request headers for both those image request attempts too? Text would be better than image if you can do that.

Comment: @msbit I added the request header.  They are the same except for the 'user-agent'.  So the code is the same, the requests are the same, but the responses are different.  Must be something to do with the browser/machine right? Can't think of any other explanation.  Or maybe something pre-flight-related?

Comment: Hmm, that rules out my theory that the request triggering the problem response was missing the `Origin` header. If I was troubleshooting this, I would grab the curl command from the Chrome DevTools for the network request on the "bad" machine (`Network` tab > right click > `Copy` > `Copy as cURL`), and then run this on both the "good" and "bad" machines, adding the `-v` argument to show the headers. Loosely, if the response to the curl command has the `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers then the server is fine, and you can isolate machine/browser through that.

Comment: Oh and on the topic of pre-flight, based on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests), these requests will be "simple" and not trigger the requirement for a pre-flight check. This gels with what I see when testing your code (ie, just the `GET` request per image).

Comment: @msbit I rand the curl command in the terminal of the "bad" machine and the `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers were indeed there. So I guess that means it's a browser issue then right? and thanks for the help

Comment: Seems likely that the browser is at fault then. Have you ensured that there isn’t any caching on the browser which could have stored a copy of the response?

Comment: @msbit oh so your thinking maybe the responses are correct, the browser just for some reason is using some past incorrect response that it has cached - I'll check

Comment: I faced the same problem: one file works, the other one does not work in the same browser. Eg a.png works, and b.png does not work on the same page. When I cleared the cache, then the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
<AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
```

with

```
<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
```

Comment: Thank you but this did not fix it.  I think I have tried every conceivable CORS configuration :) I'm leaning towards thinking this is some kind of weird browser-related issue

Comment: I faced the same problem. When I cleared the cache, then the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

CORS error removed by adding CORS configuration to my bucket but still not able to download the image.

I tried different solutions but these are the steps that worked for me. You should try these steps.

**1.** Add CORS configuration on your bucket.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

**2.** Add **crossorigin="anynymous"** to img tag

```
<img crossorigin="anonymous" id="media_img" src="example.jpeg">
```

**3.** JS code

```
  $('#media_img').on('click', () => {
    downloadImage();
  })
 
  function toDataURL(url) {
    return fetch(url).then((response) => {
      return response.blob();
    }).then(blob => {
      return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    });
  }

  async function downloadImage() {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = await toDataURL($('#media_img').attr('src'));
    a.download = 'example.jpeg';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

AllowedOrigins won't take wild card. Main domain URL has to be listed.

```
"AllowedOrigins": [
     "https://your.domain.com"
        ]
```